# Find unique combination of pandas column out of list and another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [['233182801104', '862824274124', '278711320172'], ['072287346459', '278058853506'], ['233182801104', '862824274124'], None, ['123412341234']], 'country':[None, 'France', 'USA', None, 'Germany'], 'c':np.random.randn(5), 'd':np.random.randn(5)})
```

Which looks like:

```
                                       number  country         c         d
0  [233182801104, 862824274124, 278711320172]  None     0.177375 -0.226086
1  [072287346459, 278058853506]                France  -0.134511  0.551962
2  [233182801104, 862824274124]                USA      0.490095  0.770992
3  None                                        None    -0.714745  0.807898
4  [123412341234]                                Germany  1.047809  0.523591
```

I want all unique combinations of elements of lists in the number column and the country. Additional problem is that list can very in length and number and country can contain `None`:

```
code     country_final
233182801104     USA
862824274124     USA
278711320172     None
072287346459     France   
278058853506     France   
123412341234     Germany
```

As a first step I would do this to have seperate columns

```
a['number'].apply(pd.Series)
```

After that I am not sure if I have to work with `groupby` or some kind of pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = []
for i in df.itertuples():
    for j in i[1]:
        data.append( (j,i[2]) )

df2 = pd.DataFrame( data, columns =['code' , 'country_final']
```

OR you can condense it as :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame( [ (j,i[2]) for i in df.itertuples() for j in i[1] ], columns =['code' , 'country_final']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [`unnesting`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) with `groupby` + `first`

```
s=unnesting(df.dropna(subset=['number']),['number'])
s=s.mask(s.isnull()).groupby('number').country.first().sort_values().reset_index()
s
         number  country
0  072287346459   France
1  278058853506   France
2  123412341234  Germany
3  233182801104      USA
4  862824274124      USA
5  278711320172      NaN
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```